# box-shadow no se muestra en el navbar

Tags: css, bootstrap, navbar

estoy queriendo hacer una barra de navegación (navbar)) y al momento de aplicarle un box-shadow al borde inferior, ésta no se muestra, la sombra no se muestra.

Me pasa lo mismo en otros navegadores.

Y eso que estoy siguiendo los pasos de un tutorial
Ya borré las cookies, el historial, y el caché y nada :/

Gracias por tu tiempo!

Éste es el  HTML Y EL CSS:

```css
.navbar {
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px #000;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Landing page Book</title>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP CSS-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- CUSTOM CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">

  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"> 
        <img src="img/logo.png" alt="Fazt logo" style="width: 20%;">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Team</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- BOOTSTRAP JAVASCRIP -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El código es el correcto y esta funcionando, intenta borrar cache de navegador.

Comment: Ese css lo invocas antes o después que el bootstrap?

Comment: @BetaM Después.

Comment: Trata de hacer más específico el selector así `nav.navbar` y trata